# How to change the numbering format to #,###,### on Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got an error saying `TypeError: String(...).setNumberFormat is not a function` by running the script on Google Sheets

I want to change the numeric format to #,###,### but i got an error instead after adding `const osdNumberFormat = String(row[7]).setNumberFormat("0.000");`

Here's the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Generate SP I - 1 PKS');
  menu.addItem('Generate Now!', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxx');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxx')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('1 PKS')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[11]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const subjectDateTitle = new Date(row[10]).toLocaleDateString();
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`SP I - ${row[2]} - ${subjectDateTitle}` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    //In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
      const friendlyDate = new Date(row[10]).toLocaleDateString();
      const dueDateFormat = new Date(row[9]).toLocaleDateString();
      const osdNumberFormat = String(row[7]).setNumberFormat("0.000");

    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{no_pks}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{owner_name}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{showroom_name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{address}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{print_date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{subdistrict_name}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{city_name}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{province_name}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{osd_num_amount}}', osdNumberFormat);
    body.replaceText('{{osd_alp_amount}}', row[8]);
    body.replaceText('{{due_date}}', dueDateFormat);
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 12).setValue(url)
    
  })
  
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to provided code, to get required number format, this line of code:

```
const osdNumberFormat = String(row[7]).setNumberFormat("0.000");
```

can be replaced with this line of code.

```
const osdNumberFormat = Number(row[7]).toLocaleString("en-US");
```

It can be checked, if it works.